# Topology of classical compact groups?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups

Let $O(n)$, $U(n)$, $SO(n)$ and $SU(n)$ be the orthogonal, unitary, special orthogonal and special unitary group respectively. What are the topology of these groups? (I'm just a beginner to algebraic topology, don't know much of differential topology). I am unable to find the answer to this question on the net, can someone tell me what the open sets of these topological spaces are?

My book just defines the sets and then goes on to prove that $SO(3)$ is homeomorphic to $RP^3$ without defining the topology of these groups.

Comment: They are subset of $GL(n, \mathbb R)$ and thus have the subspace topology, while $GL(n, \mathbb R)$ is identified as an open subset in $\mathbb R^{n^2}$.

Comment: I am aware of the definition of a subspace topology; however I don't know about the topology of GL(n,R)? How is a $n \times n$ matrix identified as a subset in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$?

Comment: Think of $GL(n, \mathbb R)$ as the space of invertible $n\times n$ matrices and then identify the entries with elements in $\mathbb R^{n^2}$.

Comment: @ArcticChar I see, one question though: If n = 2, and my invertible matrix is [1 2 ; 0 1] (; separates a row), then is this matrix identified as (1 2 0 1) of R^4 or (1 0 2 1) of R^4 or it doesn't matter? Also I'm guessing as GL(n,R) needs to be invertible, it is a proper subset of $R^{n^2}$ with the subspace topology?

Comment: It doesn't matter how you put the entries. Also, it's a proper subset: indeed it's the set $\{ M : \det M \neq 0\}$, which is an open set since $\det$ is continuous.

Comment: Matrices have an operator norm, you can use that too to induce the topology. It's the same topology as any vector space topology will be isomorphic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All these groups are subgroups of the monoid $M  = M(n,\mathbb R)$ of real $(n \times n)$-matrices (note that the monoidal structure on $M$ is given by matrix multiplication). But $M(n,\mathbb R)$ is a real vector space of dimension  $n^2$ which can be identified via a linear isomorphism $\phi$ with $\mathbb R^{n^2}$. This gives us a topology on $M$ making $\phi$ a homeomorphism. It is easy to see that this topology does not depend on the choice of $\phi$. Your groups receive the subspace topology. Moreover, matrix multiplication in $M$ is easily seen to be continuous with respect to this topology. Finally, on the subgroup $GL(n,\mathbb R)$ of $M$ matrix inversion is easily seen to be continuous. Both properties transfer to your groups.